# Add hyperlink like functionality in win forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, events, datagridview

My motive is to display some information as link and on click of that, I should be able to get id of clicked item and open new window with detailed information of item. As i am new in win forms but i did some research, Possible option for this might be [DataGridViewLinkColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  but i am not able to link id with column data and click event on which open new window.

Or there any other better approach possible.?

Comment: The data you're speaking of, is this already inside a datagrid?

Comment: yes i am to display data inside the datagrid as link but don't know what to do next.

Comment: ok, based on that, I added an answer - don't know if it reflects what you want to do. If not, please provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a datagridview you can get the values of a cell as follows:

Firstly, create a cellclick event

```
datagridview1.CellClick+= CellClickEvent;
```

DataGridViewCellEventArgs holds some properties, these would be rowindex (row you clicked) and columnindex (column you clicked) and some other...

make a datagrid with 2 columns, column 0 holds the Id of the row, column 1 holds the link

```
void CellClickEvent(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 if(e.ColumnIndex == 1) // i'll take column 1 as a link
 {
  var link = datagridview1[e.columnindex, e.rowindex].Value;
  var id = datagridview1[0, e.rowindex].Value;

  DoSomeThingWithLink(link, id);
 }
}

void DoSomeThingWithLink(string link, int id)
{
 var myDialog = new Dialog(link,id);
 myDialog.ShowDialog();
 myDialog.Dispose(); //Dispose object after you have used it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element.

What you could do is use the [CellClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the object. It will have a [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object passed on, on which there's a ColumnIndex property and a RowIndex property. This way you could figure out where in the the datagrid the user clicked.

And, for example, you could use that information to look up the id or other info since you now know the row & the cell the user clicked on.

arbitrary e.g.:

```
// wire up the event handler, this could be anywhere in your code
dataGridView.CellClick += dataGridView_CellClick; // when the event fires, the method dataGridView_CellClick (as shown below) will be executed

private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    var columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex; // = the cell the user clicked in

    // For example, fetching data from another cell
    var cell = dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex];

    // Depending on the cell's type* (see a list of them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s(v=vs.80).ASPX) you could cast it
    var castedCell = cell as DataGridViewTextBoxColumn;

    // Use the cell to perform action
    someActionMethod(castedCell.Property);
}
```

(*DataGridViewCell types: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s(v=vs.80).ASPX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX))

Comment: but same for you, I think yours was more complete by showing an example of adding the event handler. I edited in my answer to be complete, but will give due creds here.